# container to zip other containers

Tags: c++, boost, containers

I need a container, that wraps other containers and makes them traversible like a zip_iterator, but also wraps their other functions (like `push_back()`, `size()`, ...). Is there something like this in the `stdlib` or `boost`?

**Background:**

I have a class that stores a polymorphic base class in a `boost::ptr_list<BaseClass>` but needs some more information to be stored alongside this. With an normal `std::list` I would just do `std::list<std:pair<BaseClass, OtherInformation> >` and am done, but I want the pointer management of `boost::ptr_list`.

The obvious solution I came up with is: Have two containers `boost::ptr_list<BaseClass>` and `std::list<OtherInformation>`. This solves the problem but leaves me with always handling two containers instead of one (which also invites inconsistencies between the containers).

So I am searching for a wrapper that will wrap two (or an arbitrary number of) containers and makes them accessible like one, that stores a tuple of the data.

*To summarize:*

Either I need a container that does this, then I would like to know if there is already one or if I have to implement it my self (which I would consider some fun :).

Or the solution I thought of is the wrong way to go, then please tell me the alternatives.

Comment: Why not `boost::ptr_list<std::pair<BaseClass, OtherInformation>>`?

Comment: @jrok It must be at least `<boost::ptr_list<std::pair<BaseClass*, OtherInformation> >`, because Baseclass is an abstract baseclass. Also I doublet that pair will class delete on its `BaseClass*` entry (that was the reason I'd used `ptr_list` in the first place)

Comment: Right. But you can use a smart pointer.

Comment: You mean like: `std::list<std::pair<boost::scoped_pointer<BaseClass>, OtherInformation> >`? This would be possible although I liked the `ptr_list` for giving the elements away as references and not pointers (looks a bit cleaner).

Comment: Why not ``std::list<std:pair<std::unique_ptr<BaseClass>, OtherInformation> >``? Your ``boost_scoped_ptr`` could also work.

Comment: @juanchopanza Looks like the one I posted. I think I will go with the `std::unique_ptr` (as it is more "standard").

Comment: Have you considered `ptr_multimap<OtherInformation, BaseClass>`?  It's backwards, but it could work.

Comment: @ecatmur That is overkill. In my scenario I want to use this structure as a simple stack.